# c# dynamic and extension method solution?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection

I have a method in `Base class` which calls ( by reflection to *another* method).

```
  type.InvokeMember(context.Request["MethodName"],
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance, 
                    null, 
                    this, 
                    new object[] { context, Jobj });   //  jObj is dynamic
```

**jObj** parameter type is `dynamic` ( can't change this type).

if the `MethodName` string value is :  "`getFinanceDetails`" so that method is called..

```
void getFinanceDetails(object contextObj, dynamic obj)
{

  //Here I need to do obj["Inv_num"].ToString().Decrpyt()   ( my extension method).
  //but it goes Bang cause I cant use extension method for dynamic.
  //But I cant also send it decrypted from base cause not all values are encrpyrted.

}
```

However - I did solve it by using (inside the method):

```
((object) obj["Inv_num"]).ToString().Decrypt();
```

But I dont want to cast every time to object , just to enable extension method.

Is there anything I can do with the *param type sending* to fix it ?

**my desire :**

I want to be able to do :  <strike>`obj.ToString().Decrpyt()`</strike> `obj["Inv_num"].ToString().Decrpyt()`

## edit

```
   public static string Decrypt(this string obj)
        {
            Func<string, string> Decrypt = Encryptions.GetDecryptedCode;
            return Decrypt(obj);

        }
```

- obj ( **in this case** is `IDictionary<string , object>`) .
  so I should be able to read properties. (inv_num in this sample.

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough information. What *exactly* is your extension method? What does `obj.ToString()` return? What's the relevance of `["Inv_nim"]`?

Comment: Can't you cast jObj before invoking the method? `new object[] { (YourType)jObj })` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: And why would you expect `ToString()` to know to return `obj["Inv_num"]`?

Comment: @JonSkeet the ToString is there only for the extension method which is applied on `this string obj`.( if I understand your question)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: This is getting maddening. You say you want to *just* be able to write `obj.ToString().Decrypt()` - which doesn't involve the indexer at all. So what value would you expect `obj.ToString()` to return if you *could* do that?

Comment: @JonSkeet .oh I'm so sorry. I deserve a downvote. I didnt  see the floosh desire. it should be `obj["Inv_num"].ToString().Decrypt()` and not `obj.ToString().Decrpyt()`. **Im so sorry.**

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Right, that *completely* changes the question. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: again @Jon , and all others **Im so sorry**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `obj["Inv_num"].ToString()` already returns the right value, you could easily do it in two steps:

```
string text = obj["Inv_num"].ToString();
var decrypted = text.Decrypt();
```

To be honest, it's not clear why `getFinanceDetails` (which should be changed to follow .NET naming conventions) can't be written as:

```
void getFinanceDetails(object contextObj, IDictionary<string, object> obj)
{
    var decrypted = obj["Inv_num"].ToString().Decrypt();
}
```

Do you ever need to call it with something that *doesn't* implement `IDictionary<string, object>`?

Comment: `getFinanceDetails` cant be called as object becuase I wont be able to do : obj["xxx"]. (where in run time the type is dictionary....]

Comment: @RoyiNamir: But your original question said you just wanted to be able to do `obj.ToString().Decrypt()` - with no mention of `obj["Inv_num"]`. You're being *very* unclear about your requirements. (And could you change the type to `IDictionary<string, object>`?

Comment: I think it is clear why `getFinanceDetails` can't be rewritten as proposed: It's because dynamic expressions are evaluated at runtime, but extension methods are rebuilt by the compiler (at compile-time). So the runtime tries to invoke `obj.Decrypt()` and not `Extensions.Decrypt(obj)` because the compiler doesn't know that the extension method should be invoked.

Comment: yeah it did work. I changed to signature as your solution. and now Im able to do  `obj["Inv_num"].ToString().Decrypt()`

Comment: Jon did you mean by _following .net conventions_  : to change to [g] ? to uppercase ? or to change its name  to `FinanceGetDetails` or both ?  or none `:(` ...I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045(v=vs.100).aspx but just want to know what part were you referencing.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, changing it to `GetFinanceDetails`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not exactly the syntax you were looking for but you could call the extension method as a simple static method on the dynamic object:

```
void getFinanceDetails(object contextObj, dynamic obj)
{
    var decryptedValue = MyExtensions.Decrypt(obj);
}
```

This obviously assumes that at runtime `obj` is of the correct type that your extension method operates on. In your question you have shown some `obj["Inv_num"]` as if `obj` was a complex type with a property called `Inv_num` which is of type string. So you might need to adjust the call on the proper type:

```
var decryptedValue = MyExtensions.Decrypt(obj["Inv_num"]);
```

Comment: Thanks but I was trying to prevent this _method call wrapper_. and only do "fluent" method calling  like `x.Do().Do2()`

Comment: You can't invoke an extension method on a dynamic object. This is not supported by the programming language you are using (C#). I have proposed you a workaround. The other workaround is not to use any `dynamic` type at all.